# Actual locations of my friends

Tags: facebook, location, facebook-fql

I want to create a list with the most actual location of my friends. 
For this i retrieve data from checkin, `location_post` and `photo_tag`. 
I realized that if one of my friends upload a photo with a locationinfo i need to query the photo table too.

Where else can i get location info from? Or can you suggest an `FQL` query which retrieves all these locations in one?

Answer (score 0):

you can do that using Graph API.
here is description from docs together with working example

**from docs:**
Objects with location. The following will return information about objects that have location information attached.
There are important behavioral differences in the results depending on the permissions your app has acquired.

> To read Posts with location information, you need:    user_photos or
>   friends_photos for Photos     user_status or friends_status for Posts
>   (not including Photos)    user_checkins or friends_checkins for Checkins
>   only (excluding all other types of Posts)

**working api call example to load all checkins:**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=checkin&until=now&limit=50&access_token=valid_access_token
```

Comment: WareNinja, thanks for the reply. i did test that, but seems it doesnt supply info older than 3-4 days. I run this search first: me/home?with=location&until=now, it retrieves 10-12 checkins/photos/posts on the first result page, and only 2 on the second (clicking on the next link). when i manually changed the "until" field i got no results when i set it before 1st of august: me/home?with=location&until=1343900000  So this would be good, if i could retrieve a longer period. also, can i access this search from fql too, or just from the graph.api? thanks again

Comment: or is this search the same? SELECT author_uid , id, page_id, coords, type, timestamp FROM location_post WHERE  ( author_uid=me() OR author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())) AND timestamp>0

Comment: did you try appending since=  and until=  for defined period in old?

Comment: Yes i did. i works strange. if i retrieve the 1500+ locations in 100 items batches than for XY i get only 7 checkins. if i modify the "( author_uid=me() OR author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())" to get only XY's locations ("( author_uid='XY')") than i get 8 checkins and 3 photos. WHY???!!! :) sorry i really gont understand it.. is my code buggy or the FQL engine?

Comment: yeah fsq may act shaky sometimes.  solution is simpler though. you can implement periodic checker that runs every 1 hour and retrieve location_posts with since -90 mins and store them in db. in this case, you will also have a copy of the date piling in your db on top of what you can query from facebook. avoid your db from growing too much, i can suggest keeping data backwards max 1 week, that should be enough to enrich what u get from facebook on each query. how it sounds?

Comment: yes, what you say is logical, and i already do this (when the app starts reads up all the history, and later just reads the locs between lastpoll-now). the only problem that this doesnt solve is what is with those locations that are not given back by the first poll. what i can do is take the users one by one and retrieve their location histories. i just didnt want to do this cause now i run 15 FQLs, and than i have to run 400 :) i will check if that gives back more locations than i get now. let you know. and thaks for the help again